# "Label not Found", though defined in Java source code

Tags: java, loops

I have been trying to figure out how to make it so players could choose to restart the game at the end, but whenever I try to restart the loop, it says

```
Label Game was not found
```

even though it is clearly shown in this code.

```
        // System objects
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        // Game variables
        String[] enemies = {"Skeleton", "Zombie", "Warrior", "Assassin"};
        int maxEnemyHealth = 75;
        int enemyAttackDamage = 25;
        int enemyDeaths = 0;
        List scores = new ArrayList();

        // Player variables
        int health = 100;
        int attackDamage = 50;
        int numHealthPotions = 3;
        int healthPotionHealAmount = 30;
        int healthPotionDropChance = 50; // Percentage


        boolean running = true;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Dungeon!");

        Game:
        while(running) {
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");

            int enemyHealth = rand.nextInt(maxEnemyHealth);
            String enemy = enemies[rand.nextInt(enemies.length)];
            System.out.println("\t# " + enemy + " has appeared! #\n");

            while(enemyHealth > 0) {
                System.out.println("\tYour HP: "+ health);
                System.out.println("\t" + enemy + "'s HP:" + enemyHealth);
                System.out.println("\n\tWhat would you like to do?");
                System.out.println("\t1. Attack");
                System.out.println("\t2. Drink Health Potion");
                System.out.println("\t3. Run");



                String input = in.nextLine();
                if(input.equals("1")) {
                    int damageDealt = rand.nextInt(attackDamage);
                    int damageTaken = rand.nextInt(enemyAttackDamage);

                    enemyHealth -= damageDealt;
                    health -= damageTaken;

                    System.out.println("\t> You strike the " + enemy + " for " + damageDealt + " damage. ");
                    System.out.println("\t> You received " + damageTaken + " in retaliation");

                    if(health < 1) {
                    System.out.println("\t> You have taken too much damage! You are too weak to go on!");
                    break;
                    }
                }
                else if(input.equals("2")) {
                    if(numHealthPotions > 0) {
                        health += healthPotionHealAmount;
                        numHealthPotions--;
                        System.out.println("\t> You drink a health potion, healing yourself for " + healthPotionHealAmount + "."
                        + "\n\t> You now have " + health + " HP"
                        + "\n\t> You have " + numHealthPotions + " health potions left.\n");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("\t> You have no health potions left! Defeat enemies for a chance to get one!");


                    }

                }
                else if(input.equals("3")) {
                    System.out.println("\tYou ran away from the " + enemy + "!");
                    continue Game;


                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("\tInvalid Command");
                }
            }
            if(health < 1) {
                System.out.println("You limp out of the dungeon, weak from battle");
                break;
            }
            enemyDeaths++;
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(" # " + enemy + " was defeated! #");
            System.out.println(" # You have " + health + " HP left. #");
            System.out.println(" # Your current score is " + enemyDeaths * 100 + " # ");

            if(rand.nextInt(100) < healthPotionDropChance) {
                numHealthPotions++;
                System.out.println(" # The " + enemy + " dropped a health potion! #");
                System.out.println(" # You have " + numHealthPotions + " health potion(s). # ");
            }
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("What would you like to do now?");
            System.out.println("1. Continue fighting");
            System.out.println("2. Exit Dungeon");

            String input = in.nextLine();

            while(!input.equals("1") && !input.equals("2")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Command");
                input = in.nextLine();
            }
            if (input.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println("You continue on your adventure!");
            }
            else if (input.equals("2")) {
                System.out.println("You exit the dungeon, successful from your adventures!");
                scores.add(enemyDeaths * 100);
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("######################");
        System.out.println("# THANKS FOR PLAYING #");
        System.out.println("######################");
        String randomWords;
        in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a name to be remembered by");
        randomWords = in.next();
        scores.add(randomWords + " " + enemyDeaths * 100);
        System.out.println(scores);
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("\n");
        {       
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");

            String input = in.nextLine();

            if(input.equals("yes")) {
                continue Game;          
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the number of `}` doesn't really match the number of `{`

Read the new user's help, and especially, provide a **minimal** verifiable example. As a hint, boiling down a problem to the minimum thing you'd need to do to recreate it immensely helps us and yourself solve it.

Comment: This line is the issue: `continue Game;`. `continue` is a reserved key-word. Look at a Oracle tutorial to understand what it means: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 0):

it's easier if you set the opposite:

```
if(input.equals("no")) running = false;
```

That way the while loop gets out cleanly and you don't need to use a cumbersome label to control your flow.

Comment: I think you wanted to use "no" - using 'no' would not compile.

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple, you could just change the exit criteria:

```
if (!input.equals("yes")) {
    break; // end the loop
}
```

Just a hint: it is considered a good practice to compare a literal against some variable:

```
if (!"yes".equals(input)) {
    break; // end the loop
}
```

Doing the check this way will not fail with `NullPointerException` in case `input` is `null`, it just returns `false` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

From

[Branching Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

> The continue statement skips the current iteration of a for, while , or do-while loop.

You want to jump to the label 'Game' from outside of the labelled while loop,
which is not allowed.